# C# Visible values of enum

Tags: c#, logic

I am a beginner in programming and I have a problem with enums. Maybe its impossible to do what I want. Here is my code:

```
    public static class  Browser
    {
       public static WebBrowser browser = WebBrowser.IE;
       public static Resolution resolution = GetRes(browser);

       public static Resolution GetRes(WebBrowser browser)
       {
           Resolution res;
           if(browser == WebBrowser.Chrome)
           {
               // COMPILATOR_ERROR: res = Resolution._800x600;
               // NOT_ERROR: res = Resolution._1024x768; 
           }

           return res;
       }
    }        

public enum WebBrowser
{
    Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera
}
public enum Resolution
{
    _800x600, _1024x768, _1280x800
}
```

I have created method where I want do a magic. If `browser` will be `WebBrowser.Chrome`, then for `res` will be visible only `_1024x768, _1280x800` from `Resolution`. If not, then compilator get an error. Maybe this is a bad solution with enums, but I hope you understand what I want to do. Is there some optimal way how to do something like this?

Comment: Just make and fill your own array of `Resolution` depending on the browser, and select from that, instead of using the enum itself.

Comment: There is no options to throw compile-time error. It is runtime check.